# Can't run a simple WinForms app, shows a default unchanged form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am reading a book of HF series on C# and have to do a first simple WinForms app, which contains a button, a checkbox and a label. I created the controls and an event handler for the button with code, didn't make any changes to other files, just the Designer and the file with C# code (don't know how it is called properly).
Saved it all.

[image: Program content]

When I try to run the program (F5 or Ctrl+F5), VS shows me a default form as if it was blank and without any elements.

[image: How the program looks when executed]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add a parameterless constructor which calls `InitializeComponents`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code inside of Form1.cs:

```
  public Form1()
  {
        InitializeComponent();
  }
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! I am wondering why VS didn't add the code automatically as in previous times.

Answer (score 1):

If the above solution is not working :

In your program.cs, your probably call Application.Run(new Form()) instead on Application.Run(new Form**1**())

You instantiate a default form, and not the class you created.